# GROUP BY How to filter out groups with a similarly written value in another row of same table?

Tags: mysql

Let's asume for simplicity I have a table with this data:

```
Color    Temp  Value
-----    ----  -----
red      hot     1
red      cold    1
red      mild    2
red      hot     2
red      cold    3
blue     hot     1
blue     cold    2
blue     hot     2
blue     mild    3
blue     hot     3
blue     cold    2
green    hot     1
yellow   hot     1
yellow   mild    1
yellow   cold    4
yellow   hot     3
reddish  hot     1
reddish  mild    3
reddish  cold    4
purple   hot     1
purple   mild    3
purple   cold    2
```

I want to query the table grouping and counting the occurrences of each color and have this exclusions

1) exclude groups with less than 2 occurences, therefore I would want to exclude the "green" group

2) exclude groups where at least one of the rows of that group contains "4" in the "value" column. Therefore exclude the "yellow" and the "reddish" groups

3) exclude groups when there also exists at least one row in the table with a similarly written color(LIKE 'color%'?) that has "4" in the "value" column. Therefore I would want to exclude the "red" group, because there is a row with color "reddish" and value "4"

So In the example data I put I would expect my query to return only:

```
Color    Count(*)
-----    --------
blue        6
purple      3
```

I suspect this query should use some mix of JOIN clauses, use of variables and/or subqueries with maybe LIKE CONCAT, but all these are kind of new to me so I cannot seem to arrive to a working query. Or maybe it is a lot simpler than that.

Anybody knows how to write this query?
Many thanks.

Comment: first is easy: `group by color having count(*) > 2`. the rest, not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause to set conditions on aggregation. For your first two conditions, the query would look like this:

```
SELECT color, COUNT(*) AS colorCount
FROM myTable
GROUP BY color
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 AND SUM(val = 4) = 0;
```

This query will only return the count for groups that have at least 2 rows, and where no rows where value = 4. The last condition is a little tricky, and I do not think you can solve this using a `HAVING` clause.

What I would do is start by considering this as a separate issue, and then working it in later. To get all rows where val = 4, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT color
FROM myTable
WHERE val = 4;
```

Once you have that, you can JOIN it to it's related colors like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.color
FROM myTable m
JOIN(
  SELECT DISTINCT color
  FROM myTable
  WHERE val = 4) tmp ON tmp.color LIKE CONCAT(m.color, '%');
```

In your example, the above query would return 'red'. So, to exclude red from your final results, you can use the `NOT IN` operator. I used that operator on the first result set so that the condition is only checked on the resulting aggregated rows:

```
SELECT color, colorCount
FROM(
  SELECT color, COUNT(*) AS colorCount
  FROM myTable
  GROUP BY color
  HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2 AND SUM(val = 4) = 0) tmp
WHERE color NOT IN(
  SELECT DISTINCT m.color
  FROM myTable m
  JOIN(
    SELECT DISTINCT color
    FROM myTable
    WHERE val = 4) tmp ON tmp.color LIKE CONCAT(m.color, '%'));
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6ad7d/5) example with your sample data.

Comment: I tried your approach step by step to better understand it but when I execute the 3rd of the 4 queries it stays "thinking" for some minutes and the pops up "Lost connection to MYSQL server during query". Not sure if the LIKE CONCAT is too resource intensive on my 250000 rows table or I just have some configuration that needs some change. Probably the latter

Comment: @dodecafonico which query? The one after `related colors like this:` ?

Comment: but it's probably some problem not related to the query, because the same thing is happening to me when I have created some indexes. I have had to shutdown and restart the server then go back and the indexes are created fine

Comment: @dodecafonico it's possible that it's a configuration. Using the `CONCAT()` function may draw extra resources because it is a function, but I'm not sure 250,000 is enough to slow it down. Let me know if you figure it out. It worked fine in SQL Fiddle, I'm unable to test in the workbench right now though, I will when I can.

Comment: yes, your query definetely works as requested so I'll mark this as solved(thank you very much). I'll investigate a little bit my issue and I might create a new question if I cannot figure out what's wrong. Cheers :-)

Comment: @dodecafonico glad to help! If you do need to ask another question, comment here so I get a notification because I'm definitely curious. Feel free to upvote, too ;P

Comment: After seeing that when running the same query in the mysql command line after some minutes the results were actually returned with no error, I figured it was something to do with my client(Navicat for mac). I found the solution here: http://wiki.navicat.com/wiki/index.php/Lost_connection_to_server_during_query. I increased the default value from 30 to 60 and now it is not giving me that lost connection error.